# WordPress errors in admin: Missing pages, missing posts, error editing pages and posts

Tags: wordpress, admin

I have the weirdest error on my WordPress site. Front end is working properly, but on the admin there are some issues.

- Pages page shows "No pages found" but the upper filter shows correct number of pages.
- Posts page shows "Wrong content type" when trying to load.
- Trying to edit a page or post gives "You don't have permission to access this page" (Admin user, credentials are ok, permissions in users meta table are ok)

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't change ANYTHING on that site for months now.

Comment: I turned all plugins off and on again. Nothing.

Answer (score 3):

After a few frustrating hours I found out that a specific Apache version is causing this set of errors.

Apache version 2.4.26 breaks WordPress admin, here's the bug report:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61202

There's a nice thread filled with others who had that issue, and it's solution:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/invalid-post-type-on-wp-adminedit-php/

Solution is (drumroll): Add this line to your .htaccess file. yep, that's it.

```
ProxyFCGIBackendType GENERIC
```

bye :)